# Why gives AttributeAppender the error Can't instantiate page using constructor?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a class MylistPage3 thats works fine.

```
public class MyListPage3 extends WebPage {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Model<String> infostringMdl = Model.of("Info: -");
    Model<String> classModelOfMsg = Model.of("btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block");
    Label infolabel = new Label("info", infostringMdl);

    public MyListPage3(final PageParameters parameters) {
        infolabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        infostringMdl.setObject("Hello World");
        classModelOfMsg.setObject("btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block");
        //infolabel.add(new AttributeAppender("class", classModelOfMsg, " "));
        add(infolabel);
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
...
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width:="50%"><span wicket:id="info"
            class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">info here</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
```

I want to set the class of the span with Java, but with the line...

```
infolabel.add(new AttributeAppender("class", classModelOfMsg, " "));
```

...I get the error:

```
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor public Pages.MyListPage3(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 

Root cause:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.behavior.Behavior
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
...
...
```

I run mvn dependency:tree 
The result is:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WicketExamples 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ WicketExamples ---
[INFO] com.mkyong.core:WicketExamples:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:jar:6.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:jar:6.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:jar:6.21.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket:jar:1.4.17:compile
[INFO] +- de.agilecoders.wicket:wicket-bootstrap-core:jar:0.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars:wicket-webjars:jar:0.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.webjars:webjars-locator:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:2.3.1-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.webjars:jquery:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:modernizr:jar:2.6.2-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket-extensions:jar:6.21.0:compile
[INFO] +- de.agilecoders.wicket:wicket-bootstrap-extensions:jar:0.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:v20130411:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:jquerypp:jar:1.0b2:compile
[INFO] +- de.agilecoders.wicket:wicket-bootstrap-themes:jar:0.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.473 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-12T20:10:30+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is going wrong here?

Is org.apache.wicket:wicket:jar:1.4.17 here the source of the error?

Comment: I've created a test page.. Everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Sanluck. How are your settings for Wicket in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Check your application classpath. It looks like there are several versions of Wicket in it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Martin. I am new at Wicket. How can i check the classpath? In pom.xml?

Comment: In Eclipse IDE you can expand the `Maven Dependencies` item in the `Project Explorer` and have a look at all the JAR files in the class path (given the Eclipse project is a Maven project).

Comment: You can run `mvn dependency:tree` and look for wicket jars with different versions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Imperative and Martin!

I updated the question with the result of mvn dependency:tree.

Is org.apache.wicket:wicket:jar:1.4.17 here the source of the error? I tried to set the dependency in the pom-file to 6.21.0, but then I get errors with mvn clean install.

Comment: I think you right - it must not be `wicket-1.4.17` and `wicket-core-6.21.0` both in dependencies. Try to remove `wicket-1.4.17` it's old version of Wicket.

Comment: Martin, Sanluck and Imperative, thanks for your comments! It works! Indeed, there were several versions of Wicket in pom.xml.